PyPlot plots are bigger with high DPI, but still blurry
I am following a tutorial to generate a scatter plot of points, coloured by cluster and also colour-saturated based each point's strength of membership in its respective clusters.  I mention the colouring details in case they affect the resolution, but I suspect they don't.
What I find is that if I increase the DPI of a PyPlot figure, the figure increases in size, but is still very blurry.  Below is my test code, which generates a small DPI figure and a large DPI figure.  The latter still seems extraordinarily blurry.  What is causing this and how can I get sharp plots?  I am using Spyder.
# Adapted from:
# https://hdbscan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced_hdbscan.html

# Generate plot data
#-------------------
import numpy as np
data = np.load('clusterable_data.npy') # https://github.com/lmcinnes/hdbscan/blob/master/notebooks/clusterable_data.npy
import hdbscan
clusterer = hdbscan.HDBSCAN(min_cluster_size=15).fit(data)
import seaborn as sns
color_palette = sns.color_palette( 'deep',
   len( np.unique( clusterer.labels_ ) ) )
cluster_colors = [color_palette[x] if x >= 0
                  else (0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
                  for x in clusterer.labels_]
cluster_member_colors = [sns.desaturate(x, p) for x, p in
   zip(cluster_colors, clusterer.probabilities_)]

# Plot the scatter graph
#-----------------------
%matplotlib tk
   # To get separate window in Spyder
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.close('all')

# Low resolution
plt.rcParams['figure.dpi']=50
plt.scatter(*data.T, s=50, linewidth=0, c=cluster_member_colors, alpha=0.25)

# High resolution
plt.rcParams['figure.dpi']=150
plt.figure()
plt.scatter(*data.T, s=50, linewidth=0, c=cluster_member_colors, alpha=0.25)



They're blurry because you've set alpha=0.25, so the points are all nearly transparent.

What about the plot is blurry? The points or the tick marks/labels?

@jared: The points look blurry, but as Tim Roberts said, it seems to be due to the alpha=0.25.

@Tim Roberts: You're right. The following do not look blurry: plt.scatter(*data.T,s=50,linewidth=1,edgecolors=cluster_member_colors,facecolor="None") and plt.scatter(*data.T,s=50,linewidth=0,c=cluster_member_colors,alpha=1).  Thank you.  Did you want to post the answer?

They're blurry because you've set alpha=0.25, so the points are all nearly transparent.  If you want transparency, then blurry is a side effect.  If you don't want blurry, then play with the alpha value.
